# Adobe AIR: detect en_GB locale

Tags: localization, air, locale

Is there a way to detect if the user is running the AIR application under en_GB locale on Windows? Capabilities.language returns only "en" and Capabilities.languages[0] returns "en_US" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.
But it will be something soon (sorry, can't tell you more now)!

Check here: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/event/index.cfm?event=detail&id=1489921

> "Get the inside scoop on the new
>   mobile features in Flash Player 10.1,
>   as well as the new global error
>   handling, UI, **globalization**, and media
>   playback features."

Comment: This is what I was talking about: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/
From "What's new" look for Globalization for an overview
The namespace is flash.globalization (not sure if the documentation is posted, I will look for it)

Comment: Documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/package-detail.html

And in the download page, "Getting Started" step 9 gives a link to the swc to use for Flex Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Now the globalization features are out in Flash Player 10.1 you can use them. Check out the documentation for them here: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/package-detail.html

and more info here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_globalization_package.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader

You can easily get the default local as a string like so:

```
new StringTools(LocaleID.DEFAULT).actualLocaleIDName; // returns en-GB if region is United Kingdom on OSX
```